# why is O(n^2) vs O(ab) different?

Tags: java, algorithm

My problem is what is the difference between O(n^2) vs O(ab). There are two different N arrays in a nested for loop. From the CTCI, i've read that it is not O(N^2) rather O(ab) because it has different inputs.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arrayB.length; j++) {

    }
}
```

Comment: if arrays had same length it would be O(n^2). If there are two arrays of length `a` and `b` then it is `O(ab)`.

Comment: `n^2 = n * n`. `n` can't be two different numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simple:

Because doing something like (a) 1 x (b) 10 million ... only takes 10 million "time slots".

Whereas (n) 10 million x (n) 10 million ... well, that's always n*n, isn't it.

In other words: O(ab) expresses that you have **two** parameters that determine complexity. O(n^2) expresses that your complexity *only* depends on one parameter.

Answer (score 2):

> why is O(n^2) vs O(ab) different?

`O(n^2)` translates to `O(n*n)`, its complexity depends only on 1 variable. Your example depends on 2 independent variables, the complexity is therefore not necessarily quadratic to any of those two. If you have for example a very small `b` and a very high `a`, your complexity would be almost linear dependent on a.

The only case where those two expressions would be equal is when `n = a = b`, then `O(n^2) = O(a*b)` would apply.

Answer (score 2):

If a and b are the same length, then it's O(n^2), else it's O(ab)

Answer (score 0):

Because it depends on the properties of the application/inputs.

If either a or b remains low or constant, then O(ab) scales like O(n) rather than O(n^2).